# jQuery: How to set different action for each loop only for first row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a large, dynamically created table that contains 3 columns, one for amounts that need to be subtracted, one for amounts that need to be added and one for the sum of each row.

**So far I have the below which works as intended.**
However, on the first row of the tbody it doesn't make sense to check for the sum from the previous row as there is no previous row.
Only in this case it should take the initial balance which appears in a th of the thead (class = `"calcStart"`) instead of the sum of a previous row.

**Can someone tell me how I can achieve this ?

Also,** if there is something that can be written better / shorter in the code I have please let me know as well.

**My JS:**

```
var calcMinus, calcPlus;
var calcSum = 0;
$(document).on('keyup', '.calcMinus, .calcPlus', function(){
    $(this).closest('table tbody').find('td.calcSum').each(function(){
        calcMinus = Number( $(this).closest('tr').find('td.calcMinus').find('div').text() );
        calcPlus = Number( $(this).closest('tr').find('td.calcPlus').find('div').text() );
        if((calcMinus == '') && (calcPlus == '')){
            $(this).text('0');
        }else{
            calcSum += Number( $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td.calcSum').text() );
            calcSum -= calcMinus;
            calcSum += calcPlus;
            $(this).text(calcSum);
        }
        calcSum = 0;
    });
});
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: [`jQuery.not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: It's very hard to say without seeing the HTML. Please set up a working example, ideally using StackOverflow code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code  .. use `:gt()` selector

[:gt(0)](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

> Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched
>   set.

```
$(this).closest('table tbody').find('td.calcSum:gt(0)').each(function(){
```

if you wan to skip first th then use below code

```
$(this).closest('table tbody').find('th:gt(0) td.calcSum').each(function(){
```

As  Discussed with OP here another option to avoid first row

pass index in each function with index parametar

```
$(this).closest('table tbody').find('td.calcSum').each(function(index){ 
if (index === 0){}else{} });
```

Comment: Thanks - is this for the first row ?

Comment: Thanks - let me try this.

Comment: can you post your HTML ?

Comment: if you wan to skip first th  then   `$(this).closest('table tbody').find('th:gt(0) td.calcSum').each(function(){`

Comment: Thanks - this works for the part to skip the first row. How do I address the first row then ? I can't post HTML here as the table is created dynamically.

Comment: have you check my both option in answer ?  here row means fisrt `th` or `tr` ?

Comment: you can get HTML table from browser console .. you can  inspect element and copy table HTML  :)

Comment: Thanks - your solution works to skip the first row which is fine for the rest of the table but for the first tbody row only I need to so something different so I need to address this somehow separately as well.

Comment: that alos easy if you pass index in each function like this  `$(this).closest('table tbody').find('td.calcSum').each(function(index){  if (index === 0){}else{} }`